# Preventing INFO exceptions from being logged to App Insights

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, host.json

There's a question/answer explaining how to get rid of specific exceptions:

[Preventing Specific Exceptions from being logged to app insights](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65568843/3231884)

I don't need anything as complex as this, as I want to get rid of **all exceptions of type info** (LogLevel=info) for namespace "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus". Is this possible? I tried the following:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "logLevel": {
                "default": "Information",
                "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus": "Warning"
            }
        },
        "logLevel": {
            "default": "Information",
            "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus": "Warning",
        }
    }
}
```

*host.json*

Unfortunately it doesn't work, as "Exceptions are logged at the Error level.":
[Azure Functions Monitoring Log Level Categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-categories)

I was now looking to the "isExceptionSnappointsEnabled" flag, which might be what I want, but I'm not sure. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The value of the log level configures the logger to send logs of that severity or higher. You can refer to [this table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-log-levels) for the levels available.

In your case, you could set the value to `Warning` or higher level.

Comment: That's what I did (just check my host.json). Still, no luck.

Comment: Your `default` is set to `Information`. Have you tried changing that to `Warning` or higher?

Comment: The default is 'Information' because I want the 'Warning' (or higher) to be effective exclusively on the namespace "Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus".

Comment: You mention you want to get rid of all logs of type information. Is that not the case though? Sorry if I'm misunderstanding something obvious here. Could you elaborate and share some logs highlighting what you want to not have?

Comment: PramodValala-MSFT, thumbs up for your comments, I updated my question as I shouldn't have said that